# javascript: set onclick function with a parameter for a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a button using javascript and now I want to give it a onclick. however I want the function to have a parameter i. the problem is that when I inspect the console the onclick function is just onclick=playAudio(i). I want it to be different for each value of i in the for loop, but because it is in brackets it just stays as i instead of the current number in the for loop. I hope I have explained this properly. some of the code is below to help you understand.

```
var i;
var audioMp3 = ["audio/Un", "audio/Deux", "audio/Trois", "audio/Quatre", "audio/Cinq", "audio/Six", "audio/Sept", "audio/Huit", "audio/Neuf", "audio/Dix"];

for(i = 0; i < audioMp3.length; i++{
    var audioBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    audioBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "playAudio(i);";
}
```

Comment: Just use right concatenation `audioBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "playAudio("+i+");"`

Comment: audioBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "playAudio('+i+');");

Answer (score 3):

```js
var audioMp3 = ["audio/Un", "audio/Deux", "audio/Trois", "audio/Quatre", "audio/Cinq", "audio/Six", "audio/Sept", "audio/Huit", "audio/Neuf", "audio/Dix"];

for(var i = 0; i < audioMp3.length; i++){
    var node = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(audioMp3[i]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    node.setAttribute("onclick", "playAudio("+i+");");
    document.getElementById("element").appendChild(node);
}
function playAudio(i){
alert(i);
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this should work :

```
audioBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "playAudio("+i+");");
```

Answer (score 0):

audioBtn.onclick = function(){
 playAudio(i)
}

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with all the possible values, loop through the values to create the buttons, each button should have their click event listener to play their own button's song.

I don't know your precise code but that is the pseudo-code to do it.